# Getting infinite recursion in Rails as_json routine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, infinite

I have an Account class that has_many stores.  In the Store class, there is a routine that returns all the other stores for that account:

```
def other_stores
  if account then
    account.stores.find(:all,:conditions=>"id != "+id.to_s)
  else
    []
  end
end
```

When I include :other_stores in my as_json routine and then reference it, I pin a cpu and hang.  I am assuming it is infinite recursion in the other_stores.  Any ideas?  Any way to stop the recursion?

Ruby 1.9.2-p136, Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

It most likely looks like this, let's say you have `[@store1, @store2]`

```
@store1.as_json
#as_json calls @store1.other_stores() ==> [@store2]
  @store2.as_json
  #as_json calls @store2.other_stores() ==> [@store1]
    @store1.as_json
    #calls @store1.other_stores() other_stores ==> [@store2]
```

The easiest fix is to pass in the ids that have already been rendered:

```
def as_json(rendered_ids = [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wondered about that approach.  I think I figured it out, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.  This seems to be working:

```
def as_json(options={}) 
  super(:methods => [:blah, :etc, 
                     :other_stores => {:except => :other_stores} ]) 
end
```

Chris

Comment: Nope, I was wrong (dumbass).  That is causing other_stores to not show up in the json at all.